# SQL - Agrupar resultado de consulta en un campo

Tags: php, postgresql, sql

estoy programando un script en php y he creado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT t2.id_usuario, t3.nombre, to_char(t1.fichaje_fecha, 'YYYY-MM') AS mes
,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.operacion = '+' THEN t1.tiempo ELSE '00:00:00' END ) AS "positivo"
,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.operacion = '-' THEN t1.tiempo ELSE '00:00:00' END ) AS "negativo"

FROM produccion.bolsa_horas AS t1
INNER JOIN produccion.fichaje AS t2 ON t1.id_fichaje = t2.id_fichaje
INNER JOIN produccion.usuario AS t3 ON t2.id_usuario = t3.id_usuario

WHERE t1.fichaje_fecha > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months') AND t1.alta = true AND t2.id_usuario = 1

GROUP BY t2.id_usuario, t3.nombre, t3.apellido1, to_char(t1.fichaje_fecha, 'YYYY-MM'), t1.operacion
ORDER BY t2.id_usuario, mes
```

Por la cual me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me gustaría obtener es en una misma linea el acumulado de positivo y negativo mensual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un poco el contexto es que tengo una base de datos en la cual se guarda información relativa a los fichajes de los trabajadores y me piden un recuento mensual de su bolsa de horas(diferencia entre saldo positivo y negativo) por el momento lo que quiero lograr es que me devuelva en una sola linea el positivo y negativo acumulado por mes.

El handicap es la tabla donde almacena la bolsa de horas guarda movimientos positivos o negativos en una sola columna con lo cual no puedo agrupar por operación.

Se me escapa de mis conocimientos si me orientáis os lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: quita t1.operacion del group by

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel! Era tan fácil com no agrupar por t1.operacion. En su momento lo hice pero también modifiqué el CASE y me daba error al agrupar.

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo con esta consulta:

```
SELECT t2.id_usuario, t3.nombre, to_char(t1.fichaje_fecha, 'YYYY-MM') AS mes
,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.operacion = '+' THEN t1.tiempo ELSE '00:00:00' END ) AS "positivo"
,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.operacion = '-' THEN t1.tiempo ELSE '00:00:00' END ) AS "negativo"    
FROM produccion.bolsa_horas AS t1
INNER JOIN produccion.fichaje AS t2 ON t1.id_fichaje = t2.id_fichaje
INNER JOIN produccion.usuario AS t3 ON t2.id_usuario = t3.id_usuario    
WHERE t1.fichaje_fecha > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months') AND t1.alta = true AND t2.id_usuario = 1    
GROUP BY t2.id_usuario, t3.nombre, t3.apellido1, to_char(t1.fichaje_fecha, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY t2.id_usuario, mes
```

Comment: Alberto, tu respuesta se verá mejor das formato al código. Es muy fácil, solo tienes que [edit], seleccionar el código y presionar el botón `{ }` o la el atajo de teclado `Control+K`.

Comment: Gracias @Alberto! Efectivamente era tan sencillo como no agrupar por t1.operacion @amenadiel se adelantó en la respuesta pero no le puedo asignar puntos así que te los asigno a ti ;)